Why do azeotropes behave the way they do?
I read this answer to a similar question whilst it proved to be plenty insightful there was this one point I failed to understand:

To get a minimum boiling azeotrope, the deviation from Raoult's Law requires that the vapor pressure of the lower boiling component be reduced from what is predicted for ideal behavior and that the vapor pressure of the higher boiling component be increased.

Maybe I have completely misunderstood something because I thought vapour pressure of both should be reduced as boiling point is directly proportional to pressure and the minimum bp azeotrope has a boiling point less than the constituents' individual one?
Even as I write this, I believe I might be overlooking something glaringly obvious but I really cant pinpoint what it is.

The explanation that makes the moist sense to me is, "the vapour has the same proportions of constituents as the unboiled mixture."
How does that happen? As the lower-boiling constituent is more rapidly removed from the boiling mixture, the remaining mix becomes more concentrated with the higher-boiling component. Therefore, there is greater probability for the high-boiling component to be removed, by the law of mass action.

hmm but doesnt that explain why the equilibrium is maintained rather than why that equilibrium (of constant composition in liquid and vapour phase) exists in the first place?  sorry I am new to thermodynamics
